# App won't reopen after closing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm developing an iOS app.

I have placed it in a workspace with other targets (frameworks) that I use in the app. I can run the app fine, but once double tap the home button and I close it completely, I can't run it again. 
I tap on the icon, and sometimes it launches the app then quits immediately, or sometimes it simply doesn't open it.

Is there a way to fix it or to find what is causing this problem?

PD: the reason why I'm doing this is to test wether reopening the app from a local notification loads the correct data for the notification that has been opened. Trying to open by tapping on the notification doesn't work either.

Neither the debugger or the console are printing anything out.

Comment: Where exactly does the app crash ?

Comment: Does your console show anything about error?

Comment: @UmairAfzal the app crashes right after I open it, it shows the loading screen for a second and then crashes.

Comment: @BharatNakum the console can't show anything, as it crashes when I try open the app from another project. Here is what I do: I open another project, run it, close the app it runs, then try open the actual app on the simulator by tapping the icon. At this point it crashes

Comment: Try to unistall the app from simulator, then run it from Xcode. Then stop the app, Close it from simulator and run it again from Xcode. You will see the point of crash

Comment: @BharatNakum the app crashes after I close it, but I think this is normal behaviour, when I try to open it again, it doesn't and nothing is printed out

Comment: You mean you're swiping it up from the app switcher while it was running from Xcode? You should explain why you're testing this way and look at the device log to see what it says...

Comment: @Wain I have edited the question

Comment: You really must test this on a device. And you should be testing it by asking Xcode to start and wait for external activation.

Comment: I will test on a device as soon as I have a chance,  I just found it strange since other apps on the simulator don't behave that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you use frameworks in your project that were not customized to work properly in the simulator. Basically, the iOS simulator uses `i383` (for 32-bit) and `x86_64` architectures, rather than the `arm` and `arm64` architectures that the real devices use. For some reason, when you create a framework, Xcode doesn't set it up to retain the compiled `i386`/`x86_64` architecture code after the app is quit. It will, however, retain the compiled `arm`/`arm64` code, so you can be sure that the app will function normally on real devices.

I personally get around this issue by using real devices when I need to test features that rely on quitting and relaunching, but there are ways to write custom build schemes on your framework to fully support the simulator. I'm not going to put a link here, though, because the specific workarounds are very diverse and I myself have not tested any of them.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!